# How to flatten complex data types in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a input.txt looks like the following:

```
{"item":[{"sdb_id":107817,"quantity":1},{"sdb_id":101733,"quantity":1}],"table_id":62}
{"item":[{"sdb_id":107795,"quantity":1},{"sdb_id":107785,"quantity":1}],"table_id":62}
{"item":[{"sdb_id":107836,"quantity":1}],"table_id":34}
```

Here I already loaded the input.txt.

```
raw_data = LOAD 'input.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS (json:map[]);

item_data = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE json#'item AS (item:{(sdb_id:int, quantity:int)});
```

And the DUMP item_data looks like:

```
([{"sdb_id":107817,"quantity":1},{"sdb_id":101733,"quantity":1}])
([{"sdb_id":107795,"quantity":1},{"sdb_id":107785,"quantity":1}])
([{"sdb_id":107836,"quantity":1}])
```

My question is how can I get the ouput looks like the following (only "sdb_id" value and "quantity" value):

```
(107817, 1)
(101733, 1)
(107795, 1)
(107785, 1)
(107836, 1)
```

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the script below, I have altered JsonLoader to do a nested load -

```
raw_data = LOAD 'input.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map[]);
b = foreach raw_data generate flatten(json#'item') as (k:MAP[]);
c = foreach b generate k#'sdb_id', k#'quantity';
```

Hope this helps.